# Showing that the index of two groups is a power of $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I am trying to understand a proof (from a book) that there are at most $(n-1)/4$ non-wittnesses against the primality of $n$ in the Miller-Rabin algorithm that are coprime to $n$.

We set the prime factorisation of $n$ to $n = \prod_{p | n} p^{e(p)}$.

In one passage the author considers the following two subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$

$K = \{ a + n\mathbb{Z} : gcd(a,n) = 1 \text{ and } a^{n-1} \equiv \pm 1 \text{ mod } p^{e(p)} \text{ for all primes $p$ such that } p | n\}$

$M = \{ a + n\mathbb{Z} : gcd(a,n) = 1 \text{ and } a^{m} \equiv 1 \text{ mod } n\}$.

He observes that $M \le K$ which is clear. Then he says that the index $(K : M)$ is a power of $2$ since the square of each element of $K$ is an element in $M$. I can not follow this argumentation, could you please explain that to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group, written multiplicatively, and $H$ a subgroup.
If $a^2\in H$ for all $a\in G$, then $\overline a^2$ is the identity element
 in the quotient group $G/H$ (where $\overline a$ is the image of $a\in G/H$).
The order of $\overline a$ in $G/H$ is either $1$ or $2$.

If the order of $G/H$ is not a power of two, it has an odd prime factor $p$.
By Cauchy's theorem, $G/H$ would then have an element of order $p$; this gives
a contradiction.